# Overlapping text

Tags: css, html, text

I would like to know how to make my text wrap properly when zoomed out in a browser? I mean the page looks fine when normally zoomed but when you zoom out by pressing Ctrl + "+" then it overlaps over the image on the right side of it. I have tried the white-space:nowrap but it doesn't give me the results I want. Can any of you please help me out?? Been trying to solve this for quite a while now also to help you guys better understand I have attached an image of how it looks like.

HTML:-

```
 <p class="aboutus-description">
 Integer tristique consequat nulla, sed convallis urna dictum sit amet. Ut at ligula dolor, id cursus sem. Nullam sed dolor eu.
 Ut ante nunc, posuere ac varius sit amet, bibendum non est. Morbi in arcu in felis pharetra sodales vitae non.
 Sed dictum cursus leo, sit amet semper est commodo in. Etiam.

 Nunc elit sem, bibendum ac laoreet quis, accumsan sed neque. Integer lacus nisi, lobortis faucibus ornare non, cursus non augue. Suspendisse.
 Vivamus hendrerit laoreet mauris ut molestie. Nullam auctor nulla ac ligula viverra nec adipiscing tellus eleifend. Duis ligula enim, semper eget
 Vestibulum erat diam, cursus ut semper sit amet, feugiat a erat. Praesent vestibulum, quam ac.
 Maecenas non risus dictum neque sodales commodo sed quis massa. Morbi mollis, odio.
```

CSS:-

```
<style>
#content p.aboutus-description
   {
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size:10pt;
     color:#656565;
     position:absolute;
     left:80px;
     top:20px;
     width:747px;
     overflow-style:auto;
     white-space:nowrap;
     word-wrap:break-word;
   }
```

Image:-

[image]

Comment: this information is not good enough please provide more

Comment: Please post your full HTML (including the image)

Comment: Why do you want to create a page that looks perfect if the user is zooming in/out like that? That is not considered standard behaviour really... A lot of pages can break when you do that.

Comment: @NullPointer I have added the image now, hope that helps you understand.

Comment: @Mr.Flocker No, I mean the image tag in your HTML, not a snapshot of the page. The HTML you have posted is just a single unclosed paragraph tag. We need to see the `img` tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by `float:left;` to the content and `float:right:` to the image
and remove the position:absolute from `#content p.aboutus-description`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help :( as I said I can view it normal when zoomed out but whenever I zoom it, it starts overlapping.